# vista: moved and messed up default "documents", "contacts" and "desktop" folder locations

Tags: windows-vista

Afternoon all,

This is what I did, can anyone tell me how to get out of this dead end please? ...

1. "Fresh install" of vista onto C: actually just did a factory restore using the HP tool
2. Created a new partition for data = F:
3. Moved the "documents" folder with the following method [a] Start [b] right click on "documents" select properties [c] location tab [d] move [e] select F: [f] accept the dialogue box that said "do you want to move all the files from the old location to the new location? ... We recommend ... "
4. Moved the "contacts" folder with the same method as above [a-f] plus there was another dialogue box [g] accepted "Do you want to redirect the folder "contacts" into another system folder located at "F:\" If you proceed with the redirection you will not be able to seperate them or restore default location." [h] Then there was another dialogue box which said "There is already a file with the same name in this location. Click the file you want to keep". desktop.ini. Options = copy & replace/ don't copy/ copy but keep both files. I selected the 'copy & replace' *** I assume this was the step I really really shouldn't have done ***
5. Moved the desktop folder using exactly the same method as for contacts.

So now my documents, desktop and contacts are all the same. Erp. really not very good. I suspect that I reload all my documents from before the factory restore they're going to appear as desktop items .

I tried right clicking on each of the folders and changing the location to a new one (C:\first) but I got a message saying "failed to build the list of regular subfolders under "F:\System Volume Information" Access is denied" - which I simply don't understand.

So. How do I get out of this?

Can I create 3 new folders and edit or replace each one's desktop.ini file to recreate the separate desktop/ contacts/ documents? Do I need to download an ini file/ ini settings or something?

thanks in advance for any help at all.

Answer (score 1):

The outcome is exactly what should have been expected.  You set the Documents, Contacts and Desktop folder to the same location...the root of the F drive.

The redirection steps taken do not create each a separate folder in the location you choose, it uses that location.  To make each its own folder you must redirect each to three different locations like

```
F:\Documents
F:\Contacts
F:\Desktop
```

or the following which makes Contacts and Desktop a sub folder of your Documents assuming you leave it directly in the root of F:

```
F:\
F:\Contacts
F:\Desktop
```